# Llenar una variable en PHP cuando una consulta de vacio en MySQL

Tags: php, sql

Al hacer una consulta MySQL en PHP el extraido no te arroja nada asi le asigne una variable el extraido no lo toma ni como null ni como cero a pesar de que haya creado la variable como hago para asignar un valor a una variable en php para consultas vacias? les dejo el codigo

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT tanquenum from tanque WHERE tanqedo = 'Ocupado'")
        or die ("Error de consulta");
while ($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {

       echo $extraido['tanquenum'];
       $p=$extraido['tanquenum'];
       echo gettype($p)."<br>";
}
```

el valor de `$p` no toma ningun tipo de variable ni es llenada, necesito llenarla para hacer otro procedimiento cuando la consulta sea vacia

Comment: Que te muestra en el `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

La puedes inicializar antes del bucle
`$p = 'loquequieras';
while ...`

Answer (score 0):

(PHP) Una solución sencilla sería inicializar la variable **$p** con un valor vacío y, posteriormente, agregar un condicional simple, donde utilices la función EMPTY para verificar que una variable está vacía. Es decir, tu código debería quedar de a siguiente forma:

```
$p = ""; //La variable inicia con vacío

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT tanquenum from tanque WHERE 
tanqedo = 'Ocupado'") or die ("Error de consulta");

while ($extraido =  mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
 echo $extraido['tanquenum'];
 $p=$extraido['tanquenum']; 
 echo gettype($p)."<br>"; 
}

/*Condicional simple para verificar que la variable aún está vacía, y, de ser 
así, le agregamos un valor por defecto*/

if(empty($p == "")){
  $p = 'CualquierValor'; //Agregas el valor que quieras
  echo gettype($p)."<br>"; 
}
```

Para que complementes, te dejo e link de la documentación oficial de PHP para la función EMPTY.

[Documentación EMPTY de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)